# Odd NSView display performance

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I am adding a custom NSView to my NSWindow's content view. Whenever I go to interact with any subviews of this new NSView (some NSTextFields, an NSMatrix, NSPopUpButton and NSButton), that specific part of the view seems to disappear and show the subview.

The parts of the view that go missing never return. Does anyone know what would be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have overlapping sibling views?

Comment: I do have another NSView within the NSView in question.

Comment: Overlapping sibling views means two views that belong to the same superview, i.e., one is not a subview of the other one, and they both have frames which overlap. Is that the case?

Comment: Well, the NSView that I am adding has a smaller NSView as a subview of that view. As far as I know that shouldn't be a problem? I tried removing the subview and the problem still occurs.

Comment: If overlapping views are always subviews, it shouldn’t be a problem. It can be a problem when they’re sibling views (i.e., share the same direct superview) because Cocoa doesn’t guarantee correct behaviour in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a common problem. I ended up having to add this view as a child window of my application's window.

This link was very useful: http://blog.stuntaz.org/cocoa/2009/11/03/nswindow-overlay.html